# arch installation- startx not working

Tags: xorg, arch-linux

I went through the Arch installation yesterday, everything seemed to be going fine but when I ran `startx` it gave an error(in image below)-
[image: error message when I ran startx]

Is it a problem with the graphics card driver? My laptop has Intel GL40 and I've installed the 
xf86-video-intel driver; is it the correct one?

Comment: What does the log file /var/log/Xorg.0.log say?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have  you installed xterm and twm? It doesn't appear so from that screenshot.

Make sure you install all of the Xorg base packages:

```
# pacman -S xorg-server xorg-xinit xorg-utils xorg-server-utils
```

[From the Arch Beginners' Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners_Guide#Install_X)

Comment: @jasonwryan- Yes, I've already installed those packages but still it doesn't work

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - neither package is found. Install them explicitly: # pacman -S xorg-twm xorg-xclock xterm

Comment: `# pacman -S xorg-twm xorg-xclock xterm` made it work. Thanks!

Comment: Your link has broken -- now it is "Installation Guide" and there is no "Install X" section! Moreover the package `xorg-server-utils` no longer exists.

Comment: @cat Rolling release: answer was *seven* years ago: feel free to update...

Comment: I know it's an old answer, and if I knew how to fix it I would, but I am looking for answers currently

Comment: @cat Ask a question and include all the relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure that this is *NOT* the problem with X itself, you have to observe the below commands:

> 1. X  => This will start the bare X with mouse pointer. If it comes, your X is fine. Press alt+ctrl+backspace to get back to console again.
> 2. Xorg -configure   => Configure the xorg.conf for the underlying hardware.
> 3. Xorg -config ~/xorg.conf.new  => Start the X with this new config file.

Here ~ is your home directory.

This will start the X, with the configuration as per your ~/.xinitrc file. If you have the xterm, then create the ~/.xinitrc file as

> $ cat ~/.xinitrc
>
> xterm

Make this file executable.

Comment: In Arch, you start X with the command: startx - and Ctrl-Alt-Backspace is disabled by default... Also, he doesn't need an xorg.conf

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you installed xorg but not a single window/desktop manager.  Try this:
`pacman -S slim xfce4 xfce4-goodies`  this should install a whole bunch of stuff; normally that's annoying but in your case you want to 'catch up' your distro to all the libraries a normal desktop needs.

Once that's done, either enable slim in /etc/inittab (and disable any other session manager that's enabled, usually it's xdm by default), or I think you could also start slim as a service (you can do that in Debian, I don't have access to my Arch right now).

Comment: You don't need to install a display manager (Slim) or a desktop environment (XFCE) to run X...